# what files should I exclude/add/copy mysql dbs (without mysqldump)

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-processing

I need to have an exact copy of my databases in a clone VM of my server (just in case the server goes down, have the VM ready with the dbs). I know that mysqldump is the best alternative to migrate, but I want to have another alternative. So I decided to do it with [ROBOCOPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy), and copy `data` folder. This is my batch

```
@echo off
set exclude=*.pid *.err *.cnf *logfile* *log_file*
set ORIGIN="mysql_data_path\data"
set DEST="mysql_data_path_mirror\data"

NET STOP mysqld
robocopy "%ORIGIN%" "%DEST%" /E /COPYALL /PURGE /MIR /IS /IT /TEE /FFT /ETA /R:10 /W:5 /ZB /V /XF %exclude%
```

The problem is that I am not sure which files I should exclude/add/copy, that does not affect the operation when I do the reverse process.

For example, I have put some exclusions (`*.pid *.err *.cnf *logfile* *log_file*`), but I do not know if they are correct. I would like help in this point. And, apart from `data` folder, is there anything else that I should copy in order to function in the VM?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot exclude the `ib_logfile*` files, if those aren't present, your data will be at best damaged, unless you are running with `innodb_fast_shutdown=0` - which can make stopping the service take a very long time.

The only things that are safe to omit are the relay logs and binary logs. You will have to check what the names of those are set to in your config file.

Comment: Is this enough (.pid *.err *.cnf *log_file) or should I add, remove, or copy something else?

Comment: You probably want to save the .cnf. You need to check your config file to make sure that the `*log_file` pattern isn't something important.

Comment: OK (Then only exclude *.pid and *.err). Anything else i need to exclude or copy to make it work on the VM??

Comment: Replication binlog and relay log can be excluded. Look at the name pattern in your log-bin configuration parameter. You cannot guess these things, you need to actually look at what the file names are for various things, as defined in your configuration file(s).

Comment: Your answer is not very clear to me. However I appreciate the help you have given me so far. Keep investigating

Comment: You need to find your my.ini configuration file and look for the names of various file name patterns configured for various things in there. `log-bin` defines the name of the replication binlog, for example. Replication binlog and relay log can be excluded. Innodb log files and tablespaces have to be backed up. If you don't know what these are and would rather not read the documentation, back up everything.

Comment: I only excluded * .pid and * .err and it worked perfect. Thanks for everything

Comment: new question similar https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267754/can-i-exclude-or-delete-pem-files-in-backup-data-myqdl

Answer (score 2):

`mysqldump` is a logical level tool that creates the SQL script reproducing DB at some state. There are some tools like Percona XtraBackup that makes a copy on a physical level. XtraBackup allows so-called incremental backups so you can do a full initial backup once and then you can save only diffs since last backup.

You have to refer manuals to decide what way is suitable for your needs.

Comment: great but only for linux https://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-XtraBackup-LATEST/

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop mysql.
2. Copy the entire tree.  (`rsync` or LVM makes this faster.)
3. Start mysql.

Meanwhile, make a copy of the my.cnf file(s).

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "entire tree"? (By the way, Rsync is for Linux-based OS only and ROBOCOPY is fast enough for the task)

Comment: cwrsync is alternative rsync for windows https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync

Comment: is there a way to copy ONE database and not the whole tree? what metadata needs to be transfered as well as the actual binary directory for the database?

Comment: @math - Maybe -- Are all the tables using the same ENGINE?  Which Engine.  Any stored routines?  Foreign Keys?

Comment: no routines or foreign keys. same engine, just a different datastamp on the filesystem snapshot. seems if the database exists with the same tables I can copy right overtop it it works, but if there's any new/dropped tables, things get wonky.