# can I exclude or delete .pem files in backup data myqdl?

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line

I am making a backup of the mysql data folder. In this folder are the databases. The method I am using is described in [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/266878/208609) which uses [ROBOCOPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

During installation, mysql (tested in 5.7.30) generates the following .pem files by default (at least in the wampserver version. I'm not sure if in the other versions):

```
private_key.pem
public_key.pem
server-cert.pem
server-key.pem
ca-key.pem
client-cert.pem
client-key.pem
```

the question is: What happens if I don't backup these files or delete them?

**tests performed:**
I have stopped the mysql service and I have removed all the .pem files and when I start mysql again only these .pem files appear

```
private_key.pem
public_key.pem
```

What about the rest?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are needed  for the mysql to generate nbew ssl keys

So to answer your question

> You have to decide if you want ssl or not, so if you use ssl and have user created some  client certificates with it you need it, if not you don't need them.

When you active ssl in my.ini

like

```
ssl=1
ssl-ca="\sslfolder\ca-cert.pem"
ssl-cert="\sslfolder\server-cert.pem"
ssl-key="\sslfolder\server-key.pem"
```

you can  allow a user only to access via ssl

First you generate a new ssl certificate for a user exampleuser

and add like this the use of ssl

```
CREATE USER 'exampleuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'secretsparrworf' REQUIRE X509;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'exampleuser'@'localhost';
```

fionaööy you can access mysql via ssl like this

```
mysql -u exampleuser-p --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem
```

Comment: Your explanation is very good but it doesn't answer my question. Could you expand it and answer my question?

Comment: I expanded my answer, although o thought the answer was obvious

Comment: Your explanation makes me conclude that I must keep them because they may eventually be necessary. Thanks

Comment: you can alwayxs create nmew ones and you can also use "official" ssl files which aere certificated by a certified certification authority , you ssl server key is self created and would get a messages that tells you so.